# java.lang.ClassCastException happens when Spring application starts up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize
>   class
>   org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter

the root cause is

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
>   org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter$$Lambda$1320/1372257576
>   to org.xml.sax.EntityResolver

It happens when running unit tests by surefire, the spring version is 5.0.13.RELEASE.

the error code in spring is

```
private static final EntityResolver NO_OP_ENTITY_RESOLVER =
            (publicId, systemId) -> new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
```

quite not sure how did this happened. Have anyone saw this before?

Comment: Generally things like this occur when using incompatible versions of jars. Please add your `pom.xml` to the question.

Comment: because it's long, refer to [link](https://github.com/crosslover/troubleshoot/blob/master/pom.xml) @M. Deinum

Comment: You are excluding a lot of dependencies and managing a lot yourself instead of letting Spring Boot handle them. You are using a Spring Cloud version that is incompatible with Spring Boot 2.0 it is for an older version, which might lead to inclusion of older jars/versions leading to errors. Find the correct compatible version.

Comment: It's caused by jdk version problem according to my tests :( maybe the root cause is some modification of type inference mechanism. @M. Deinum